# Deleting records in Django via forms

Tags: django

I would like to be able to present a form to users with a dropdown list of existing records and a delete action for the selected record. So far all I can find are examples that pass the id of record to the form (such as below) and I can get this to work if I hard code the id in the function, but that's obviously not a solution. What am I missing?  Thanks.

```
def DeleteRecord(request, id):
    to_delete = get_object_or_404(MyModel, id=id)
    #+some code to check if this object belongs to the logged in user

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DeleteRecordForm(request.POST, instance=to_delete)

        if form.is_valid(): # checks CSRF
            to_delete.delete()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")

    else:
        form = DeleteRecordForm(instance=to_delete)

    data = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'deleteprimerpair.html', data)
```

Comment: Why isn't that a solution? I'm guessing the value of the select option is the id of the item you want to delete so why can't you use it?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm after, but I'm stil relatively new to this, and I'm not sure what I need to tweak in the above code. At present, it fails on initally loading the page because it's missing that 'id', whereas it should present the form, then the action buttion should reload and delete the selected option. Thanks

Comment: Nothing, the above code is just the backend view, this would be a problem on your front end of what actually calls the view and how it determines what id needs deleting

Comment: Ah ok, so how would you initally call the page, where the id would be null (and the view still works)?

Comment: Either a separate view or just move the `to_delete` inside the "if Post" and remove the reference to the instance, hard to say without knowing how its supposed to work.